# My Updateserver returns Error 510

Tags: one-click-updates, extension-update

I am struggling by deploying an update server for my extensions.
In the local environment all works good but if i switch to my public server Joomla! tells me when fetching the updateservers that all of my xml's could not been read.

--> The URLS are correct
--> The updateserver returns an error 510 as i can see in my updateservers errorlog:

```
[CLIENTSERVERIP] - - [29/Apr/2020:10:57:05 +0200] "GET /updates/myextension.xml HTTP/1.0" 510 984 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Joomla!/3.9.16 Joomla"
```

I did not found anything helpfull regarding this issue, uses the following entry:

```
<updateservers>
        <server type="extension" priority="1" name="mod_nx_oriel">
            <![CDATA[https://update.host.tld/sub/myextension.xml]]>
        </server>
    </updateservers>
```

EDIT: i've tried before also with:

```
<updateservers>
        <server type="extension" priority="1" name="mod_nx_oriel">
            https://update.host.tld/sub/myextension.xml
        </server>
    </updateservers>
```

If i open "https://update.host.tld/sub/myextension.xml" it shows my update XML.

Anyone know what i can do regarding this Error 510?

Comment: Try removing the `<![CDATA[` wrapper so that it's just `<server type="extension" priority="1" name="mod_nx_oriel">https://update.host.tld/sub/myextension.xml</server>`

Comment: Hi Lodder - sorry i missed to note that the url originaly was setted without <![CDATA[ - it was a try and had been added later without success

Comment: I've tried loading the URL in my browser. It's still trying to load so I dont think it's working

Comment: thats an example URL ;-) - because the extensions there are not free

Comment: Can you copy and paste the XML contents and replace the download URL (if it's a paid extension)?

Comment: Sorry already found out i have to check with the hoster see my answer below in a few seconds

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that (after the error.log was rendered correctly) my updateserver hoster blocks these connections:

```
[Wed Apr 29 10:44:49.949248 2020] [:error] [pid 2849] [client **IP**:48884] [client ***IP***] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 510 (phase 2). Matched phrase "Joomla" at REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent. [file "/etc/modsecurity/01_hs/bad-user-agents.conf"] [line "6"] [id "0999998"] [msg "BAD BOT - Detected and Blocked."] [severity "CRITICAL"] [hostname "update.domain.tld"] [uri "/sub/myextension.xml"] [unique_id "Xqk@gX8AAAEAAAshaooAAAAW"]
```

So now i have to talk to my hoster what the heck they are doing...

Because of the demand here is my update.xml (the file that will be called by my extension):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<updates>
    <update>
        <name>Extensionname</name>
        <description>Extension Description</description>
        <element>mod_extension</element>
        <type>module</type>
        <client>site</client>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
        <infourl title="mydomain">https://www.mydomain.tld</infourl>
        <downloads>
            <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">https://update.mydomain.tld/sub/mod_extension_v1.0.7.zip</downloadurl>
        </downloads>
        <tags>
            <tag>stable</tag>
        </tags>
        <maintainer>My Name</maintainer>
        <maintainerurl>https://www.mydomain.tld</maintainerurl>
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.[0123456789]" />
        <php_minimum>7</php_minimum>
    </update>
</updates>
```